# Implementing BackSpace with using getch() function

Tags: c++

I would like to ask about inserting and deleting characters from string. 
Here is the code:

```
void Edit::input() {
    int len = 0;
    COORD cord;
    cord.X = _x;
    cord.Y = _y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cord);
    while (true) {
        char ch = _getch();

        if (ch == 13)
        {
            break;
        }

        else if (ch == 8) 
        {   
            if (len == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            pusty.pop_back();
            std::cout << "\b  \b";
            len--;
        }
        else if (len == 6) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            pusty.push_back(ch);
            len++;
        }
        std::cout << ch;
    }
}
```

What is the problem exactly? I've got the coordinates of X and Y of the window where text will be entered in this window, length of whole string is 6 characters. The problem is in a moment when i want to use backspace when `len` value is at the last element. Then backspace creates blank space on 7th index. The picture below shows the issue. How to avoid this problem ? Thanks for all feedbacks.

[image]

Comment: Add your code, result & expected result in question as text not as images.

Comment: Isn't `\b` normally the BEL character - i.e. ring the terminal bell, if the terminal supports it?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I believe that's usually `\a` (not sure why, maybe "alert"?) Edit: yep, [linux (bash)](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html) and [windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

Comment: In response to your question. Yes I've been trying to printin \b[one space]\b but the effect was unsatisfying. Precisely the string was back spaced in this way ([ a_b_c_d] not [______] ) Sorry for format of question. I'm newbie on stack with questions

Answer (score 0):

That extra space is due to using `getch`, which echos to the console as well as returning the character to you. This means that the 7th position on the console's output is reached and thus the background is painted.

You just need to set the background colour to black (in a similar manner to how you set it to turquoise in your example) before printing `\b  \b`, then set it back to turquoise afterwards - this'll hide your phantom extra character.

Rather than using `getch`, you should really consider learning `ncurses` - it provides really helpful functions that can make life a lot easier in this sort of situation (like a `getch` equivalent that doesn't echo). And it's cross-platform, so you can use it on Windows.